# writing if conditions like a list comprehension in python

Tags: python

As I am a big fan of list comprehensions, sometimes I am tempted to write down one liner if-else statement. For example we have four lines of following statement (without list)

```
import random
if random.random() < 0.5:
   print("I am going out")
else:
   print("I am staying home")
```

is there any way to make this statement into a single line (like in list comprehension) in python, without anyway converting to list?

Comment: print(["i'm out" if random.random()<0.5 else: "i'm staying home" ])

Comment: Like `print(random.choice(['string1', 'string2']))`?

Comment: Why do you care about the number of ines?

Comment: `import corona; print("I am staying home")`

Answer (score 3):

Python has [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), allowing you to write that as:

```py
print("I am going out" if random.random() < 0.5 else "I am staying home")
```

but there are often better options, e.g. in this case:

```py
print(random.choice(["I am going out", "I am staying home"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this :

```py
import random
print("I am going out" if random.random() < 0.5 else "I am staying home")
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a list comprehension, but small if statements can sometimes benefit from inline if statements:

```
flag = random.random()
test = print("out") if flag > 0.5 else print("home")
```

**Aside**

If you did want to do this operation in a list format for some reason, it would go like this:

```
from random import random

flag_list = [random() for _ in range(10)]
lst = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in flag_list]
```

You could also filter if you wanted here instead

```
from random import random

flag_list = [random() for _ in range(10)]
lst = [x for x in flag_list if x > 0.5]
```

Alternatively you could use `map` or `filter` to do these same operations like so:

```
# example 1
lst = list(map(lambda x: 1 if x > 0.5 else 0, flag_list))
# example 2
lst = filter(map(lambda x: x > 0.5, flag_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have many two-string evaluations, something like this should work:

```
from itertools import starmap
from random import random


starmap(lambda s1, s2: print(s1 if random() < 0.5 else s2), [("bork", "mork"), …])
```